# "disable" button-->method until operation is done

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, spritebuilder

I am using the following method that invoked by pressing a button thru sprite builder.

```
- (void)method {

//static dispatch_once_t pred;    //
//dispatch_once(&pred, ^{         // run only once code below

[self performSelector:@selector(aaa) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.f];
[self performSelector:@selector(bbb) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.f];
[self performSelector:@selector(ccc) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.5f];
[self performSelector:@selector(ddd) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.f];
[self performSelector:@selector(eee) withObject:nil afterDelay:4.5f];

CCLOG(@"Received a touch");

//}); //run only once code above

}
```

as you can see from the comments i tried running it once. that works good, but if a user comes back to this scene, it's disabled until you restart the app.
how can i block this method from being executed a second time until the first time is done.
i know the code is rough, i'm just learning here....

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a `BOOL` instance variable which serves as a flag as to whether or not this action is taking place.  As soon as the method starts, check the flag.  If you need to execute, set the flag.

Add another `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` which calls a method to reset the flag back.

---

```
@implementation SomeClass {
    BOOL _onceAtATime;
}

- (void)method {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (!_onceAtATime) {
            _onceAtATime = YES;

            // do all the stuff you need to do

            [self performSelector:@selector(resetOnceAtATime) 
                       withObject:nil 
                       afterDelay:delay];
             // where delay is sufficiently long enough for all the code you
             // are executing to complete
        }
    }
}

- (void)resetOnceAtATime {
    _onceAtATime = NO;
}

@end
```

Comment: can you point me in the right direction to read some literature for this. i just can't see it. thanks.

Comment: @user2800989 I added an example.

Comment: thank you your reply. it has helped a lot. I do have one more question, if you have the time. instead of using afterDelay, how can I have it reset only when the scene is reloaded. ie. if the user went to the next scene and decided to come back to this one?

Comment: Use any of the view life-cycle methods.  `viewWillAppear:`, `viewDidAppear:`, or `viewDidDisappear:` would all work.

Comment: yeah. i figured that out the moment i pressed add comment.... damn senior moments :).
i'd love to vote your answer but i don't have the rep yet. sorry.

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way would be to use a serial NSOperationQueue as such (in Swift):

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    let queue: NSOperationQueue

    required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        queue = NSOperationQueue()
        queue.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    @IBAction func go(sender: AnyObject) {
        if (queue.operationCount == 0) {
            queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
                // do the first slow thing here
            }
            queue.addOperationWithBlock() {
                // and the next slow thing here
            }
            // ..and so on
        }
        else {
            NSLog("busy doing those things")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you. i haven't move on to swift yet. but i will DEFINITELY keep this one in my notes!

Comment: Yes, this is the stylish way of doing it.